# How to convert varchar to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert my field (dateVar = '08/2018') to a real date field. Actually i have only months and years, so i need to add just 01 like a day. 
My final result should be 2018-08-01.

```
CREATE TABLE dateTable (
    dateVar varchar(10)
);

insert into dateTable (dateVar)
values('08/2018'),('01/2015');
```

i used this to convert to date but doesnt work

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, dateVar, 103) FROM dateTable
```

Comment: i wanna convert '08/2018' to 2018-08-01

Comment: The real question is: why are you storing dates as strings in the first place?

Comment: Inherit this database. that's why i need to do big change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could concatenate missing `01`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '01/'+dateVar, 103)
FROM tab
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8e9bc3098d193051c18f00e30f05dc5f)**

To avoid problems with incorrect user input you could use `TRY_CONVERT`. In case of conversion error it will return `NULL` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should use standard formats for dates:

```
insert into dateTable (dateVar)
    values('2018-08-01'), ('2015-01-01');
```

The hyphens is ISO standard and standard in most databases.  It almost always works correctly in SQL Server, but the real SQL Server standard drops the hyphens -- `'20180801'` and `'20150101'`.

The table should then be declared to have a date for the column:

```
CREATE TABLE dateTable (
    dateVar date
);
```

If you need to see this in a particular format, use a computed variable:

```
CREATE TABLE dateTable (
    dateVar date,
    date_mmyyyy as (right(convert(varchar(10), dateVar, 103), 7))
);
```

Then `date_mmyyyy` shows the value as you would like to see it.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is just to manipulate the string into YYYYMMDD format and cast it.

```
cast(right(dateVar,4) + left(dateVar,2) + '01' as date)
```